# How to make to make each partition executed sequentially in DataFrame with scala/spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava a DataFrame,I want to make the first partition is first executed ,the second partition is second executed,this is my code,but it does not work ,what should I do to make each partition executed sequentially?

```
 val arr = Array(1, 7, 3, 3, 5,21, 7, 3, 9, 10)
        var df=sc.parallelize(arr,4).toDF("aa")
        var arrbrocast=new HashMap[Int,Double]()
        val bro=m_sparkCtx.broadcast(arrbrocast)
        val rdd=df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((partIdx,iter)=>{
          var flag=true
          println("----"+bro.value.size)
          while (flag){
            if(bro.value.contains(partIdx-1)) {
              flag = false
            }
          }
          bro.value+=(partIdx->1.0)
          println(bro.value.get(partIdx-1).get)

         iter
        })
      rdd.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data to be processed sequentially **don't use Spark**. Open the file and read input stream line by line. Theoretically you can use `SparkContext.runJob` to process specific partitions but it useless when processing full dataset.

Also this is not how broadcast variables work. You **should never** attempt to modify them when executing tasks.